# Creating a matrix that has its elements as the sum of the indices of that element

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    int matrix[n][n];

    printf("Insert the order of the matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = i + j;

    printf("The matrix is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

for a 2x2 matrix the output should be  `0 1 1 2`, but it is `1 2 1 2`, and for a 3x3 matrix it should be  `0 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 4` but it shows `2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4`

The issue is that my output is always just my first row of the matrix, repeated n times. Any help?

Comment: You should declare `int matrix[n][n];` after `scanf("%d", &n);` because `n` is 0 when you declare the array.

Comment: When you declare `int matrix[n][n]` the value of `n` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    printf("Insert the order of the matrix:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int matrix[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = i + j;

    printf("The matrix is:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not just dump code. Always explain what was wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the array with size `n` equal zero. Then the length of a row is zero, hence the offset for each consecutive row is zero, too. That means all rows are stored at the same place. As a final result, the last row's values overwrite all the previous rows.

Do input `n` *before* declaring `matrix[n][n]`.